# Moonlight stopped working on tvp.pl

Tags: 10.04, moonlight

I'm watching The Bold and the beautiful on the site:

http://www.tvp.pl/seriale/obyczajowe/moda-na-sukces/wideo

Yesterday I wanted to view next episode, however it didn't work. I checked various episodes from other points in time and none works. The "dots" that appear when a Silverlight video is loading are present, but after them there is only black screen (of death). 
I'm using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 32 bit with GNOME2 and firefox 3.6. I have all updates done.
Could somebody check if any video is working for them and tell me their setup, please?

I'm using Moonlight 3. Two days ago everything was fine but later this problem appeared.

Comment: Have you tried the [Moonlight 3 Preview](http://go-mono.com/moonlight/prerelease.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a bug in the moonlight system, if you have tried deleting the settings for moonlight and it still doesn't work, please report the bug:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs